# no match for ‘operator>’

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm having trouble overloading the less then and greater then operators. they compile fine on their own, but when they are used to define less than or equal to operators (or greater than) I get this error :

```
error: no match for ‘operator>’ (operand types are ‘Job*’ and ‘Job’)
inline bool Job::operator<= (Job rhs) { return !(this > rhs); }
```

I initially had them as `operator(const Job& rhs) { ... }`, but i dropped all the const and reference syntax to see if it would work and i was just having type issues.. but even just as is i get the same error. what am I doing wrong??

here's the code:

.cpp:

```
#include "Job.h"

void Job::setId(int i) { id = i; }
const int Job::processes () const { return process; }
const int Job::ticks() const { return tick; }

inline bool Job::operator< (Job rhs) { return (process * tick) < (rhs.processes() * rhs.ticks()); }
inline bool Job::operator> (Job rhs) { return (process * tick) > (rhs.processes() * rhs.ticks()); }
inline bool Job::operator<= (Job rhs) { return !(this > rhs); }
inline bool Job::operator>= (Job rhs) { return !(this < rhs); }
```

.h:

```
#include <string>

class Job {
public:
   Job (std::string desc, int procs, int tcks)
            : description{ desc }, process{ procs }, tick{ tcks }{};
    void setId(int id);
    const int ticks() const;
    const int processes() const;

private:
    std::string description;
const int process;
const int tick;
int id;

bool operator<(Job rhs);
bool operator>(Job rhs);
bool operator<=(Job rhs);
bool operator>=(Job rhs);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to the object, not the object itself. So, this should work:

```
inline bool Job::operator<= (Job rhs) { return !(*this > rhs); }
```

Moreover if something is `inline` it should be put in the headers, as otherwise the next .cpp using your class cannot see the implementation and thus not take advantage of inline.

Comment: Thank you! I think that may have taken me a while to figure out. I'll accept your answer when it allows me to

Comment: also, operator should be `const`